# Atom起動時にスクロールバーをつかめない

Tags: atom-editor

Atom起動時に、スクロールバーのところにマウスを載せると背景が黒くなり、スクロールバーをつかめない（ドラッグできない）のですが、何か対処法はないでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一度右方向のボタンを押して、右ペインを表示して閉じると、正常に表示されるようになります。
右ペインはGit（Create repository）とかGithubPreviewのタブがあります。

OS:Windows10
Atom1.18.0

Comment: Atom のこの issue と同じでしょうか？ https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/14803

Comment: 似てるけど違いますね。スクロールバーが完全になくなってしまいますので。。

Comment: Githubとgit-diffのパッケージを無効にしたら治ったような気がします。1.18から追加されたようなので。

Comment: お疲れ様でした :) もしよろしければ、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんか？　ひとまず原因かもしれないことについて記録を残しておいて頂けると、同じ問題で困っている方の助けになると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git管理下のファイルを開いたときに現象が発生してまして、
Atomのパッケージ管理でGithubとgit-diffのパッケージを無効にしたら、発生しなくなったようです。

atom1.18からgitのパッケージが追加されたようですね。
https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1065638.html